# variable session in php

Tags: javascript, session

I want to retrieve my id and type from the object in which I am.

Then , in a class i do :

```
$refType = $_REQUEST['refType'];

$refId = $_REQUEST['refId'];
```

and :

```
  <input id="refType" name="refType" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ****" />
  <input id="refId" name="refId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ****;?>" />
```

And when i call my page in js i do :

```
  url="addNote.php?refType="+refType+"&refId="+refId;
  window.location=url;
```

But in my url , when i try to go in my page i have :

?refType=undefined&refId=undefined

Someone can help me ? Thanks !

Comment: PHP is server side, JS is client side. You cannot access server side variables from the client, so refType and refId are not set in your JS-Code.

Comment: oh ok ... And how i can retrieve my refId and refType then ? ... :(

Comment: I think `document.getElementByID('refType').val()` in place of `refType` would get you that. This is a JS question though, not PHP. or if you have jquery `$('#refType).val()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```
url="addNote.php?refType="+document.getElementById('refType').value+"&refId="+document.getElementById('refId').value;
window.location=url;
```

Comment: yor are not getting the values, only the form fields.

Comment: Hello , now i have : refType=null&refId=null

Comment: You must use `document.getElementById('refType').value`, otherwise you're just inserting the element instead of its value.

Comment: Thanks i try this but now i have :  Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: you might need to do window.document.getElementById('refType').value Can you try that?

Comment: Same problem :(

Answer (score -1):

You can add something like that:

```
<script>
   var refType = <?php echo $refType ?>
   var refId = <?php echo $refId ?>
   var url="addNote.php?refType="+refType+"&refId="+refId;
   window.location=url;
</script>
```

Comment: Don't insert unescaped PHP variables directly into JavaScript code, there's soo many ways that can go wrong.

Comment: Hello , in my js ?

Comment: Yeap. I think your problem in "refType" and "refId". They are undefined.